# FPGA/VHDL Trying to impelement a shared memory between my Basys 3 FPGA Board and a MicroBlaze Softprocessor

Tags: memory, fpga, vivado, microblaze

I am very beginner at FPGA technologies and VHDL coding. I have a Basys 3 FPGA development board which has a Artix-7 XC7A35T-1CPG236C FPGA on it. What im trying to achieve is to create a MicroBlaze softprocessor on the FPGA (already done and blinked some LED's) and create a block ram that my FPGA and MicroBlaze shares and does not communicate to transfer data between each other. Can anyone help about this or is this even possible to achieve. Thank you all guys

I tried adding a Block Ram module to my block design and connect one of the inputs to my microblaze and the other to my fpga logic unit but microblaze uses both of them inputs so i am unable to solve this

Comment: Please clarify your question further. What I understood from your question is that, You have a microBlaze processor (PS) instantiated in the FPGA (PL), and you want to create a shared memory that both PL and PS can access. and the problem that you are facing is that, PS (microBlaze) needs two port to connect to common block ram memory and there are only two ports available with block ram (so this means you cannot connect FPGA with the same block ram)?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Micro Blaze` has occupied both the port of `AXI Block Ram`, so one way is as below:

1. Instantiate another `true dual port block ram` in the block design.
2. Also instantiate an `AXI BRAM Controller` IP in the block design
3. Connect `BRAM_PortA` with this `AXI BRAM Controller` and for that I would recommend you to use `Run Connection Automation` tool for this purpose.`Run Connection Automation` will connect the `AXI BRAM Controller` IP with the `Micro Blaze` via  an `AXI Interconnect` for you. But you have to make sure that you have enable the `M_AXI_DP` port in the `Micro Blaze` settings.
4. Next connect the `BRAM_PortB` with you desired IP in FPGA (PL).

This will create a memory in the block design that can be access from PL and PS. Here is a tcl script that creates the aforementioned block design in vivado for zed board.

```
namespace eval _tcl {
proc get_script_folder {} {
   set script_path [file normalize [info script]]
   set script_folder [file dirname $script_path]
   return $script_folder
}
}
variable script_folder
set script_folder [_tcl::get_script_folder]

################################################################
# Check if script is running in correct Vivado version.
################################################################
set scripts_vivado_version 2019.1
set current_vivado_version [version -short]

if { [string first $scripts_vivado_version $current_vivado_version] == -1 } {
   puts ""
   catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-109" "ERROR" "This script was generated using Vivado <$scripts_vivado_version> and is being run in <$current_vivado_version> of Vivado. Please run the script in Vivado <$scripts_vivado_version> then open the design in Vivado <$current_vivado_version>. Upgrade the design by running \"Tools => Report => Report IP Status...\", then run write_bd_tcl to create an updated script."}

   return 1
}

################################################################
# START
################################################################

# To test this script, run the following commands from Vivado Tcl console:
# source design_1_script.tcl

# If there is no project opened, this script will create a
# project, but make sure you do not have an existing project
# <./myproj/project_1.xpr> in the current working folder.

set list_projs [get_projects -quiet]
if { $list_projs eq "" } {
   create_project project_1 myproj -part xc7z020clg484-1
   set_property BOARD_PART em.avnet.com:zed:part0:1.4 [current_project]
}


# CHANGE DESIGN NAME HERE
variable design_name
set design_name design_1

# If you do not already have an existing IP Integrator design open,
# you can create a design using the following command:
#    create_bd_design $design_name

# Creating design if needed
set errMsg ""
set nRet 0

set cur_design [current_bd_design -quiet]
set list_cells [get_bd_cells -quiet]

if { ${design_name} eq "" } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    1) Design_name not set

   set errMsg "Please set the variable <design_name> to a non-empty value."
   set nRet 1

} elseif { ${cur_design} ne "" && ${list_cells} eq "" } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    2): Current design opened AND is empty AND names same.
   #    3): Current design opened AND is empty AND names diff; design_name NOT in project.
   #    4): Current design opened AND is empty AND names diff; design_name exists in project.

   if { $cur_design ne $design_name } {
      common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-001" "INFO" "Changing value of <design_name> from <$design_name> to <$cur_design> since current design is empty."
      set design_name [get_property NAME $cur_design]
   }
   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-002" "INFO" "Constructing design in IPI design <$cur_design>..."

} elseif { ${cur_design} ne "" && $list_cells ne "" && $cur_design eq $design_name } {
   # USE CASES:
   #    5) Current design opened AND has components AND same names.

   set errMsg "Design <$design_name> already exists in your project, please set the variable <design_name> to another value."
   set nRet 1
} elseif { [get_files -quiet ${design_name}.bd] ne "" } {
   # USE CASES: 
   #    6) Current opened design, has components, but diff names, design_name exists in project.
   #    7) No opened design, design_name exists in project.

   set errMsg "Design <$design_name> already exists in your project, please set the variable <design_name> to another value."
   set nRet 2

} else {
   # USE CASES:
   #    8) No opened design, design_name not in project.
   #    9) Current opened design, has components, but diff names, design_name not in project.

   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-003" "INFO" "Currently there is no design <$design_name> in project, so creating one..."

   create_bd_design $design_name

   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-004" "INFO" "Making design <$design_name> as current_bd_design."
   current_bd_design $design_name

}

common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-005" "INFO" "Currently the variable <design_name> is equal to \"$design_name\"."

if { $nRet != 0 } {
   catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-114" "ERROR" $errMsg}
   return $nRet
}

set bCheckIPsPassed 1
##################################################################
# CHECK IPs
##################################################################
set bCheckIPs 1
if { $bCheckIPs == 1 } {
   set list_check_ips "\ 
xilinx.com:ip:axi_bram_ctrl:4.1\
xilinx.com:ip:blk_mem_gen:8.4\
xilinx.com:ip:clk_wiz:6.0\
xilinx.com:ip:mdm:3.2\
xilinx.com:ip:microblaze:11.0\
xilinx.com:ip:proc_sys_reset:5.0\
xilinx.com:ip:lmb_bram_if_cntlr:4.0\
xilinx.com:ip:lmb_v10:3.0\
"

   set list_ips_missing ""
   common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-006" "INFO" "Checking if the following IPs exist in the project's IP catalog: $list_check_ips ."

   foreach ip_vlnv $list_check_ips {
      set ip_obj [get_ipdefs -all $ip_vlnv]
      if { $ip_obj eq "" } {
         lappend list_ips_missing $ip_vlnv
      }
   }

   if { $list_ips_missing ne "" } {
      catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-115" "ERROR" "The following IPs are not found in the IP Catalog:\n  $list_ips_missing\n\nResolution: Please add the repository containing the IP(s) to the project." }
      set bCheckIPsPassed 0
   }

}

if { $bCheckIPsPassed != 1 } {
  common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-1003" "WARNING" "Will not continue with creation of design due to the error(s) above."
  return 3
}

##################################################################
# DESIGN PROCs
##################################################################


# Hierarchical cell: microblaze_0_local_memory
proc create_hier_cell_microblaze_0_local_memory { parentCell nameHier } {

  variable script_folder

  if { $parentCell eq "" || $nameHier eq "" } {
     catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-102" "ERROR" "create_hier_cell_microblaze_0_local_memory() - Empty argument(s)!"}
     return
  }

  # Get object for parentCell
  set parentObj [get_bd_cells $parentCell]
  if { $parentObj == "" } {
     catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-100" "ERROR" "Unable to find parent cell <$parentCell>!"}
     return
  }

  # Make sure parentObj is hier blk
  set parentType [get_property TYPE $parentObj]
  if { $parentType ne "hier" } {
     catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-101" "ERROR" "Parent <$parentObj> has TYPE = <$parentType>. Expected to be <hier>."}
     return
  }

  # Save current instance; Restore later
  set oldCurInst [current_bd_instance .]

  # Set parent object as current
  current_bd_instance $parentObj

  # Create cell and set as current instance
  set hier_obj [create_bd_cell -type hier $nameHier]
  current_bd_instance $hier_obj

  # Create interface pins
  create_bd_intf_pin -mode MirroredMaster -vlnv xilinx.com:interface:lmb_rtl:1.0 DLMB

  create_bd_intf_pin -mode MirroredMaster -vlnv xilinx.com:interface:lmb_rtl:1.0 ILMB


  # Create pins
  create_bd_pin -dir I -type clk LMB_Clk
  create_bd_pin -dir I -type rst SYS_Rst

  # Create instance: dlmb_bram_if_cntlr, and set properties
  set dlmb_bram_if_cntlr [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:lmb_bram_if_cntlr:4.0 dlmb_bram_if_cntlr ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.C_ECC {0} \
 ] $dlmb_bram_if_cntlr

  # Create instance: dlmb_v10, and set properties
  set dlmb_v10 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:lmb_v10:3.0 dlmb_v10 ]

  # Create instance: ilmb_bram_if_cntlr, and set properties
  set ilmb_bram_if_cntlr [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:lmb_bram_if_cntlr:4.0 ilmb_bram_if_cntlr ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.C_ECC {0} \
 ] $ilmb_bram_if_cntlr

  # Create instance: ilmb_v10, and set properties
  set ilmb_v10 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:lmb_v10:3.0 ilmb_v10 ]

  # Create instance: lmb_bram, and set properties
  set lmb_bram [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:blk_mem_gen:8.4 lmb_bram ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.Memory_Type {True_Dual_Port_RAM} \
   CONFIG.use_bram_block {BRAM_Controller} \
 ] $lmb_bram

  # Create interface connections
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_dlmb [get_bd_intf_pins DLMB] [get_bd_intf_pins dlmb_v10/LMB_M]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_dlmb_bus [get_bd_intf_pins dlmb_bram_if_cntlr/SLMB] [get_bd_intf_pins dlmb_v10/LMB_Sl_0]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_dlmb_cntlr [get_bd_intf_pins dlmb_bram_if_cntlr/BRAM_PORT] [get_bd_intf_pins lmb_bram/BRAM_PORTA]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_ilmb [get_bd_intf_pins ILMB] [get_bd_intf_pins ilmb_v10/LMB_M]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_ilmb_bus [get_bd_intf_pins ilmb_bram_if_cntlr/SLMB] [get_bd_intf_pins ilmb_v10/LMB_Sl_0]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_ilmb_cntlr [get_bd_intf_pins ilmb_bram_if_cntlr/BRAM_PORT] [get_bd_intf_pins lmb_bram/BRAM_PORTB]

  # Create port connections
  connect_bd_net -net SYS_Rst_1 [get_bd_pins SYS_Rst] [get_bd_pins dlmb_bram_if_cntlr/LMB_Rst] [get_bd_pins dlmb_v10/SYS_Rst] [get_bd_pins ilmb_bram_if_cntlr/LMB_Rst] [get_bd_pins ilmb_v10/SYS_Rst]
  connect_bd_net -net microblaze_0_Clk [get_bd_pins LMB_Clk] [get_bd_pins dlmb_bram_if_cntlr/LMB_Clk] [get_bd_pins dlmb_v10/LMB_Clk] [get_bd_pins ilmb_bram_if_cntlr/LMB_Clk] [get_bd_pins ilmb_v10/LMB_Clk]

  # Restore current instance
  current_bd_instance $oldCurInst
}


# Procedure to create entire design; Provide argument to make
# procedure reusable. If parentCell is "", will use root.
proc create_root_design { parentCell } {

  variable script_folder
  variable design_name

  if { $parentCell eq "" } {
     set parentCell [get_bd_cells /]
  }

  # Get object for parentCell
  set parentObj [get_bd_cells $parentCell]
  if { $parentObj == "" } {
     catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-100" "ERROR" "Unable to find parent cell <$parentCell>!"}
     return
  }

  # Make sure parentObj is hier blk
  set parentType [get_property TYPE $parentObj]
  if { $parentType ne "hier" } {
     catch {common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-101" "ERROR" "Parent <$parentObj> has TYPE = <$parentType>. Expected to be <hier>."}
     return
  }

  # Save current instance; Restore later
  set oldCurInst [current_bd_instance .]

  # Set parent object as current
  current_bd_instance $parentObj


  # Create interface ports
  set diff_clock_rtl [ create_bd_intf_port -mode Slave -vlnv xilinx.com:interface:diff_clock_rtl:1.0 diff_clock_rtl ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.FREQ_HZ {100000000} \
   ] $diff_clock_rtl


  # Create ports
  set reset_rtl [ create_bd_port -dir I -type rst reset_rtl ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.POLARITY {ACTIVE_LOW} \
 ] $reset_rtl

  # Create instance: axi_bram_ctrl_0, and set properties
  set axi_bram_ctrl_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:axi_bram_ctrl:4.1 axi_bram_ctrl_0 ]

  # Create instance: axi_mem_intercon, and set properties
  set axi_mem_intercon [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:axi_interconnect:2.1 axi_mem_intercon ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.NUM_MI {1} \
 ] $axi_mem_intercon

  # Create instance: blk_mem_gen_0, and set properties
  set blk_mem_gen_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:blk_mem_gen:8.4 blk_mem_gen_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.Enable_B {Use_ENB_Pin} \
   CONFIG.Memory_Type {True_Dual_Port_RAM} \
   CONFIG.Port_B_Clock {100} \
   CONFIG.Port_B_Enable_Rate {100} \
   CONFIG.Port_B_Write_Rate {50} \
   CONFIG.Use_RSTB_Pin {true} \
 ] $blk_mem_gen_0

  # Create instance: clk_wiz_1, and set properties
  set clk_wiz_1 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:clk_wiz:6.0 clk_wiz_1 ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.PRIM_SOURCE {Differential_clock_capable_pin} \
 ] $clk_wiz_1

  # Create instance: mdm_1, and set properties
  set mdm_1 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:mdm:3.2 mdm_1 ]

  # Create instance: microblaze_0, and set properties
  set microblaze_0 [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:microblaze:11.0 microblaze_0 ]
  set_property -dict [ list \
   CONFIG.C_DEBUG_ENABLED {1} \
   CONFIG.C_D_AXI {1} \
   CONFIG.C_D_LMB {1} \
   CONFIG.C_I_LMB {1} \
 ] $microblaze_0

  # Create instance: microblaze_0_local_memory
  create_hier_cell_microblaze_0_local_memory [current_bd_instance .] microblaze_0_local_memory

  # Create instance: rst_clk_wiz_1_100M, and set properties
  set rst_clk_wiz_1_100M [ create_bd_cell -type ip -vlnv xilinx.com:ip:proc_sys_reset:5.0 rst_clk_wiz_1_100M ]

  # Create interface connections
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net axi_bram_ctrl_0_BRAM_PORTA [get_bd_intf_pins axi_bram_ctrl_0/BRAM_PORTA] [get_bd_intf_pins blk_mem_gen_0/BRAM_PORTA]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net axi_mem_intercon_M00_AXI [get_bd_intf_pins axi_bram_ctrl_0/S_AXI] [get_bd_intf_pins axi_mem_intercon/M00_AXI]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net diff_clock_rtl_1 [get_bd_intf_ports diff_clock_rtl] [get_bd_intf_pins clk_wiz_1/CLK_IN1_D]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_M_AXI_DP [get_bd_intf_pins axi_mem_intercon/S00_AXI] [get_bd_intf_pins microblaze_0/M_AXI_DP]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_debug [get_bd_intf_pins mdm_1/MBDEBUG_0] [get_bd_intf_pins microblaze_0/DEBUG]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_dlmb_1 [get_bd_intf_pins microblaze_0/DLMB] [get_bd_intf_pins microblaze_0_local_memory/DLMB]
  connect_bd_intf_net -intf_net microblaze_0_ilmb_1 [get_bd_intf_pins microblaze_0/ILMB] [get_bd_intf_pins microblaze_0_local_memory/ILMB]

  # Create port connections
  connect_bd_net -net clk_wiz_1_locked [get_bd_pins clk_wiz_1/locked] [get_bd_pins rst_clk_wiz_1_100M/dcm_locked]
  connect_bd_net -net mdm_1_debug_sys_rst [get_bd_pins clk_wiz_1/reset] [get_bd_pins mdm_1/Debug_SYS_Rst] [get_bd_pins rst_clk_wiz_1_100M/mb_debug_sys_rst]
  connect_bd_net -net microblaze_0_Clk [get_bd_pins axi_bram_ctrl_0/s_axi_aclk] [get_bd_pins axi_mem_intercon/ACLK] [get_bd_pins axi_mem_intercon/M00_ACLK] [get_bd_pins axi_mem_intercon/S00_ACLK] [get_bd_pins clk_wiz_1/clk_out1] [get_bd_pins microblaze_0/Clk] [get_bd_pins microblaze_0_local_memory/LMB_Clk] [get_bd_pins rst_clk_wiz_1_100M/slowest_sync_clk]
  connect_bd_net -net reset_rtl_1 [get_bd_ports reset_rtl] [get_bd_pins rst_clk_wiz_1_100M/ext_reset_in]
  connect_bd_net -net rst_clk_wiz_1_100M_bus_struct_reset [get_bd_pins microblaze_0_local_memory/SYS_Rst] [get_bd_pins rst_clk_wiz_1_100M/bus_struct_reset]
  connect_bd_net -net rst_clk_wiz_1_100M_mb_reset [get_bd_pins microblaze_0/Reset] [get_bd_pins rst_clk_wiz_1_100M/mb_reset]
  connect_bd_net -net rst_clk_wiz_1_100M_peripheral_aresetn [get_bd_pins axi_bram_ctrl_0/s_axi_aresetn] [get_bd_pins axi_mem_intercon/ARESETN] [get_bd_pins axi_mem_intercon/M00_ARESETN] [get_bd_pins axi_mem_intercon/S00_ARESETN] [get_bd_pins rst_clk_wiz_1_100M/peripheral_aresetn]

  # Create address segments
  create_bd_addr_seg -range 0x00002000 -offset 0xC0000000 [get_bd_addr_spaces microblaze_0/Data] [get_bd_addr_segs axi_bram_ctrl_0/S_AXI/Mem0] SEG_axi_bram_ctrl_0_Mem0
  create_bd_addr_seg -range 0x00004000 -offset 0x00000000 [get_bd_addr_spaces microblaze_0/Data] [get_bd_addr_segs microblaze_0_local_memory/dlmb_bram_if_cntlr/SLMB/Mem] SEG_dlmb_bram_if_cntlr_Mem
  create_bd_addr_seg -range 0x00004000 -offset 0x00000000 [get_bd_addr_spaces microblaze_0/Instruction] [get_bd_addr_segs microblaze_0_local_memory/ilmb_bram_if_cntlr/SLMB/Mem] SEG_ilmb_bram_if_cntlr_Mem


  # Restore current instance
  current_bd_instance $oldCurInst

  save_bd_design
}
# End of create_root_design()


##################################################################
# MAIN FLOW
##################################################################

create_root_design ""


common::send_msg_id "BD_TCL-1000" "WARNING" "This Tcl script was generated from a block design that has not been validated. It is possible that design <$design_name> may result in errors during validation."
```